# How to fit VERY long condition in conditional formatting

Tags: vba, ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a very long condition, about 3,000 characters. Access has only space for about one tenth of that.

Is there some other way to set conditional formatting on a textbox besides through the dialogue, or can I do it in VBA and, if so, HOW?

I have conditional formatting on a bunch of textboxes that trigger when the report is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be curious to know if the VBA approach worked?

Another idea: create a hidden field on the form and set it's value based on your 3000-character condition. If you are just trying to have 1 conditional expression, you could give this hidden field a false/true or 0/1 value; if you want mulitple conditions, you could give it a value of 0, 1, 2, or 3 corresponding to the conditions you want applied. In either case, your conditional expression test(s) is(are) now trivial: [HiddenFieldName]=ConditionValue

Answer (score 1):

According to Access' Help topic, the FormatConditions Collection has methods (Add, Delete, Modify) which should allow you to adjust your FormatConditions with VBA code.  I've never tried, so offer no opinion as to whether this would be a practical approach for you.

I also tried to find out if there is a capacity limit for the number of characters FormatConditions can accept.  I didn't find anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manipulate Format Conditions in VBA. There's a full detailed article knowledgebase article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304104.

Code snippet here showing a basic example. Refer to the above link to get the VBA for `AddFormats`:

```
Public Function HighLightForeignKeys(argFieldName As String, argFieldValue As Integer)
    Dim FormatCondition As String
    Dim CodeReception As Integer
    FormatCondition = "[" & argFieldName & "] = " & ArgFieldValue
    With Me.ID
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add acExpression, , FormatCondition
        .FormatConditions(0).BackColor = 16510422
        AddFormats Me.ID, Me
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what you were after, since you mentioned there was only a tiny box to enter all of your conditional text.  Others have shown you VBA solutions - since you asked if that was one way to achieve it.

I have always resorted to using the "zoom" feature which is accessible via the SHIFT-F2 keystroke.  Is that what you were after?  I think it goes back several Access versions too.

A good set of Access shortcut keystrokes is here:
http://www.joyedaniels.com/keys_access.htm